# Changing column from nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(15) increases space used in database file?

Tags: sql-server

I have a large table in a SQL 2019 database, it has about 75 million rows, and is about 33GB.

This table contains a lot of text data, about 10 columns of nvarchar(max) type.

I'm testing changing the column sizes to something more specific on my staging server and I noticed that changing one nvarchar(max) column to nvarchar(15) increased the space used in database file by about 23GB.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] NVARCHAR (15) NULL;
```

The column was nullable to begin with, that didn't change.

This column is not participating in any indexes or full-text indexes.

Here is the initial result of `sp_spaceused` for the table.

| Rows | Reserved (KB) | Data (KB) | Index Size (KB) | Unused (KB) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75,172,085 | 33,004,544 | 24,867,104 | 8,107,480 | 29,960 |

Here is the initial result from `dbo.sysfiles` for the data file for the database.

| File Size (KB) | Space Used (KB) |
| --- | --- |
| 133,775,360 | 68,794,880 |

Here is the final result of `sp_spaceused` for the table.

| Rows | Reserved (KB) | Data (KB) | Index Size (KB) | Unused (KB) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75,172,085 | 56,964,800 | 48,824,264 | 8,107,488 | 33,048 |

Here is the final result from `dbo.sysfiles` for the data file for the database.

| File Size (KB) | Space Used (KB) |
| --- | --- |
| 133,775,360 | 92,755,139 |

As you can see the total size of the data file on disk did not grow, but additional space within the data file was consumed about, ~23GB.

The table data space grew by about the same ~23GB. My numbers might be off a bit because of converting between MB/KB etc.

I'm wondering why this happened. I would have expected none or relatively no change in the data file consumption. Also is there a way to free up the space that was consumed?

Comment: You've pushed storage of that column in-row so it's had to reallocate storage for the rows but hasn't freed up the space originally used when they were out-of-row

Comment: You need to shrink your database: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: But just because the file is a certain size it's not all used

Comment: You can perhaps run `alter index all on X rebuild`

Comment: Running DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'Database' , 100000) didn't change space consumed in either the database file or the table.

Comment: @DaleK that's kind of what I was thinking, but then in that space recoverable? Is it just phantom space that SQL thinks is actually consumed but will be freed at some point?

Comment: OK I just ran update statistics and it seems like that space has been "recovered" or at least marked as available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed the following command:

`UPDATE STATISTICS TableName;`

The space has been recovered or marked as available.

The size of the consumed data in the datafile and the table data size are back to approximately the original values.